# Area51 reputation total showing more than profile total reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51, commitment-phase

My Area51 site proposal, [Computer Graphics Programming](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61961/computer-graphics-programming?referrer=nX2kFSTnynk1), just got into commitment phase two days ago. Why does it show that I have 69K reputation, when I actually have 9.7K?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the combined total reputation of you and all the people you referred (there is a tool tip on "total rep", and when you click it or the "referred" link, that page expands to show them):

[image: All users referred]

It's this total that is considered when deciding how close the site is to launch.